# How to condition script based on SAP system?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am doing a task which connects excel with SAP system via SAP GUI.

I want to use `SUIM transaction` but the problem is the view is different for different systems.

For eg :

In **system A,**
i have this code :

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "suim"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").expandNode "02  1      2"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").topNode = "01  1      1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").expandNode "03  2      7"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectItem "04  2      8", "1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "04  2      8", "1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").topNode = "01  1      1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").clickLink "04  2      8", "1"
' ** START OF DIFFERENCE **
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_TAB/tabpTAB3").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_TAB/tabpTAB3/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_TAB:RSUSR002:1003/btn%_ACTGRPS_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
' ** END OF DIFFERENCE **
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = "*********"
```

and for **system B,**

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "suim"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0  
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").expandNode "02  1      2"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").topNode = "01  1      1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").expandNode "03  2      7"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectItem "04  2      8", "1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "04  2      8", "1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").topNode = "01  1      1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").clickLink "04  2      8", "1"
' ** START OF DIFFERENCE **
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_ACTGRPS_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
' ** END OF DIFFERENCE **
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = "*******"
```

So, as you see, only the lines marked have the difference.

What should I do to get a common code so that I can run in both the systems with just one code?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Private Sub MySAPSub(SystemType As String)
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "suim"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").expandNode "02 1 2"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").topNode = "01 1 1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").expandNode "03 2 7"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectItem "04 2 8", "1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "04 2 8", "1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").topNode = "01 1 1"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlTREE_CONTROL_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").clickLink "04 2 8", "1"

    If (SystemType = "ABC 100") Then
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_TAB/tabpTAB3").Select
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_TAB/tabpTAB3/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_TAB:RSUSR002:1003/btn%ACTGRPS%APP%-VALU_PUSH").press
    ElseIf (SystemType = "ABC 200") Then
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%ACTGRPS%APP%-VALU_PUSH").press
    End If

    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = "*******"
End Sub

Private Sub CallMySAPSub()

    ' Call System ABC 100
    MySAPSub ("ABC 100")

    ' Call System ABC 200
    MySAPSub ("ABC 200")
End Sub
```

Comment: are u sure this will work?
i have two systems as ABC 100 and ABC 200

Comment: I can not test this. you must of cource edit the if statements

Comment: Can't I do this without mentioning the system name?

Comment: you need everything to decide which system you have. see my edited answer.